# How to break a while loop when you reach a certain letter in a sentence

Tags: python

I have this code I am writing and I am meant to break the while loop when the code reaches the letter 'd', but it isn't working. What did I do wrong? Also, at the end of the code I am meant o have the rest of the phrase showing and that is not working either.

```py
word_input = 'How hard is this?'
stop_at_letter = 'd'
i = 0

print('While loop a')
while i < len(word_input):
    print(word_input[i])
    i = i + 1
    if i == stop_at_letter:
        break
else:
    print('Remaining letters are:' + str(word_input))
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: `print(word_input.split(stop_at_letter, 1)[-1])` :p

Comment: `i` is an integer, your iteration counter. It will never be equal to a letter.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
if i == stop_at_letter:
```

Do:

```
if word_input[i] == stop_at_letter
```

Note: when asking questions put your code directly to its body don't post pictures with it.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing at the moment in your code is comparing the variable 'i', which I assume you're using as a counter, to the character you want to stop at.

So you're basically comparing 0 to 'd', 1 to 'd'.. etc

Instead of doing that you want to use the index to get the right character in the string ( so `word_input[i]` ) and compare that with stop_at_letter.

Also, in order to get the remainder of the word, you can use [slicing](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-substring-a-string-in-python/), which should basically look like `word_input[i:len(word_input)]`.

Answer (score 1):

It's always a good idea to copy paste your code into your post instead of posting an image, so we have an easier time reproducing your problem.

```
word_input = 'How hard is this?!'

stop_letter = 'd'

result = []

for i in word_input:
    result.append(i)
    finalResult = ''.join(result)
    
    if i == stop_letter:
        break
    
print(finalResult)
```

Output:

```
How hard
```